# Does LLVM IR allow to do Most of optimizations compared to C++?

Tags: c++, optimization, clang, llvm

There is a possibility to emit [LLVM IR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM#Intermediate_representation) in Clang:

`clang -O3 -emit-llvm -S -c main.cpp`

which produces LLVM IR assembly text `main.ll` which can be compiled later to executable through

`clang -O3 main.ll`

My question is whether second stage (with `.ll` file) does Most of possible optimizations? Or first stage (with `.cpp`) also does a lot of them?

Why do I ask? For example if I write non-optimal hand-written code of `.ll` assembly and compile it to executable, then can I expect that final program will be very optimized? Meaning if I write same-behaviour program in `.cpp` and in `.ll` can I expect that they will be about the same speed? Or writing in `.cpp` gives some extra boost? Of course C++ code is much easier to write for human, but besides that does writing in C++ compared to `.ll` gives any speed improvements?

Some people tell that writing assembly gives faster algorithms sometimes, because you have much more fine grain control over details. But here my question is a bit different - I wonder if `.cpp  ->  .ll` stage does some useful optimizations that can't be done with just `.ll`?

Comment: As one example, the C++ compiler can do [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), which actually changes observable behavior and therefore would not be allowed for the LLVM optimizer.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks. Regarding copy elision I have a question. If inside LLVM IR function I allocate and modify several registers, lets say they represent different fields of some object, then I return vector of these register values from function. I think in this case LLVM will optimize this copy semantics in a sence that it will use destination registers of function Caller to construct this object's fields instead of creating any temporary registers. In this sence I think LLVM does same copy-elision optimization, am I right? Hence LLVM have same copy-elision behaviour.

Comment: Yes, AFAIK it can do that, but it's not the same.  The C++ compiler can discard the call to the constructor altogether, including whatever side effects it may have beyone copying.  Imagine for instance that the copy constructor prints out a message.  No matter how LLVM optimizes, it has to ensure that message still gets printed.  But the C++ compiler doesn't have to ensure that, because the language allows the constructor to be elided.

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311012/what-kinds-of-optimization-llvm-does-and-what-kinds-of-optimizations-its-fronten

Comment: Yes. LLVM allows that. Whether clang does it depends on the command line options.

Comment: @arnt So basically if I write new compileable language with static types (and without extra checks, like range checks or null pointer checks, which are essential part of scripting languages like Python) which produces LLVM IR then I can expect that its speed will be about the same as C++? Basically fast speed of C++ (specifically Clang) is not due to C++ language itself but due to very good LLVM optimizer and also due to static typing and very few checks (like range checks) in standard library and language itself?

Comment: @Arty Mostly yes, but keep in mind that C++ is designed for efficiency and this has an impact on the provided feature and their cost. For example, a python modulus must be always positive while the one of C++ do not. This results in more (expensive) instructions to be generated/executed. C++ integers are fixed-size native ones while the one of Python are not. Type promotions, overflows and the strict aliasing rule as well as the numerous undefined behaviour in C++ rules tend to help compilers to generate more efficient programs. Beside this, AFAIK, the loop unrolling is done in the fontend.

Comment: @JérômeRichard BTW, I expect that LLVM also can do some loop unrolling. For example if LLVM can prove that exactly same portion of code (assembler instructions) will be executed several times except for value of single register then LLVM can just repeat this portion 4 times with precomputed values of this register for each block. In this place repeated block is a loop's body and this single register is loop's variable.

Comment: @JérômeRichard This can be generalized even more - for example if according to operations graph some subgraph is possibly repeated many times    due to conditional JUMP instructions then one can repeat code (instructions) of this subgraph several times, and handle uneven last iteration (tail) as non-repeated block. Of course this can be done only if repeat condition is some kind of simple function like comparing to range boundaries of loop, for which you can find out easily when is going to be very last tail iterations.